# Expected number of rolls given that you roll the die till you get the same or higher than previous value

Tags: probability, expected-value

Can anyone explain to me how the expectation of geometric distribution can be used here?

Comment: For clarification, does the first roll where you first determine the value of $X$ count towards this total?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Let $T$ be the number of additional rolls needed.  Do you know how $E[T]$ relates to $Pr(X=1), E[T\mid X=1], Pr(X=2), E[T\mid X=2],\dots$?  Do you know how to calculate, say, $E[T\mid X=3]$?

Comment: The best we can advise you : Roll up your sleeves and consider the different cases. Next time, show us that you don't wait an answer served on a plate...

Comment: I have used words that I use with my students : "first try, then comme back to me with precise questions". On Math SE, never present a raw question without having a minimum dialog with us : "I have tried this, I am stuck there..."

Comment: The answer is just $\sum_{i=1}^6\frac1i=2.45$

Comment: @JeanMarie How did you simulate it? I would be quite interested to see!

Comment: A couple of us have tried to format the equations using MathJax. Check that we did it correctly. Also, did you really want to use $X$ for the first roll in the first paragraph? Later you use $U$ for the first roll and $X$ for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Think of scoring $U$ or above as 'success' in a series of trials. This gives us a geometric distribution and, if the probability of success on one trial is $p$, then the number of goes before success is achieved has expectation $\frac{1}{p}.$

As you realised, there are 6 equally likely outcomes for $U$ which we have to sum over. Furthermore, $p$ is given by $\frac{7-X}{6}.$

The sum is therefore the sum of six terms each of the form$\frac{6}{7-X}$ multipled by $\frac{1}{6}$ i.e.  $\frac{1}{7-X}.$ This gives the sum which @Don Thousand gave an hour ago but which seems to have been questioned by other contributors.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

At the demand of @Don Thousand

This is not an answer. It is only to show how I have simulated the issue and found a mathematical expectation of $\approx 1.52$.

Here is my Matlab program :

> ```
> N=1000000;
> for k=1:N
>    r=ceil(6*rand);%initial roll 
>    s=ceil(6*rand);nd=1;
>    while s<r
>       s=s+ceil(6*rand);
>       nd=nd+1;
>    end;
>    T(k)=nd;
> end;
> mean(T)
> ```

Comment: You are taking a cumulative sum to meet or exceed the initial roll.  One could also read the question as asking for a single roll to meet or exceed the initial roll.  I think this latter is the preferred reading of the question, as it appears that the possible values of the random variable are unbounded.

Comment: @paw88789 I think you are right.

Comment: Indeed, I have modified "s=s+ceil(6*rand);" into "s=ceil(6*rand);" and I find now $\approx 2.45$ like the others...